# Pseudostreaming, byte range request, & mp4 fragmenting

Tags: html5-video, mp4, h.264, pseudo-streaming

Looking first for links to good documentation that correctly explains pseudostreaming, byte range requests and mp4 fragmenting.  Note, I will be using only the mp4 container (h264 codec) and HTML5 video (no flash).

My understanding of pseudostreaming is that the client can send off a start parameter that the server "seeks" to in it's response.  MOOV data must be upfront and it implicitly implies that buffering of the original source stops in favor of the new response starting at the "start"/seek position.  How is the client forced to make pseudo calls?  Does the MP4 have to formatted in a special way?

Byte range requests are different send rather than just a start parameter a range is sent.  Sounds more like progressive downloading.  How would "seeking" work?  Does it with byte range?  Can the segment size be pre-determined with movie box information?

How does MP4 fragmentation fit in?  Looking like a construct originally designed by microsoft for silverlight.  But is it applicable to other browser html5 video implementations?

Finding it difficult to sort out information on the web.  Looking to both live feed and take historical segments of h264 files produced from rtp camera streams.  Got a bunch of files time-ordered in a MongoDB.  Created my own h264 decoder in JavaScript and can construct mpeg-dash boxes on the fly off a range query.  Using Chrome's support for MSE to append segments.  Works great but not a universal solution.  Want to fall back on other techniques other than flash but with the html5 video.

Comment: Hi @Matthew, rather old question but was looking for the same info. Did you find anything useful later? Thanks.

Comment: @pembeci, aboute 2 years ago I got a prototype working that converted h264 into fragments on nodejs. Just never got around to making it public. Can always throw over the code i have to you.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. You are very kind. For now, I found [nginx mp4 module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html) which seems to be doing the job for pseudo-streaming.